# Monitoring files continuously with lsof

Tags: files, lsof

Is there a way to make lsof work continuously to monitor every file that is being opened in real time?

I don't know the name of the process. I want lsof to work continuously for a period of time until I see the the list contains what I want.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I believe since you do not know the file name/process id, you could specify user name option as below.

```
lsof -r 2 -u username
```

- The "-r 2" option puts lsof in repeat mode, with updates every 2
  seconds. (Ctrl -c quits)
- The "-u' option can be used to keep an eye on a users activity.

If you know the directory name  under which the application is being run and do not want to specify the user name,you could use the command like,

```
lsof +D /some/dir -r 2
```

**References**

[View Network Activity of any application or user in real time](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5073/view-network-activity-of-any-application-or-user-in-realtime)

Comment: @DigitalRobot, you could also refer to [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples/) link for more wonderful examples.

Comment: fantastic!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: there is a way to see what has changed in that period ? I mean sometimes the list is very large and I might just want to make something and see which files has been opened in that time.

Comment: Could a process open and close a file within the 2 second interval?